# JOption Pane Icon Placement

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane

I am trying to center my icon on in the JOptionPane.  I have read the article on here but I tried to make it work with my options that I need but its not happening.  I want to have the image on the top and the optional dialog and buttons underneath.  This is what I have so far.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img.class.getResource("zoo.png"));
    String[] options = {"Animals", "Habitat", "Exit"};
    int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Zookeepers would you like     to view animal activities or monitor habitats?",
            "Welcome to the Brooklyn Zoo!",     JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon, options,     options[0]);
```

Comment: That is not how a JOptionPane works. The Icon is only the left. If you don't like this then you need to create a custom JDialog and add your own components to the dialog.

Comment: *"I am trying to center my icon on in the JOptionPane."* Seems like futzing to me. I recommend to leave where it is and follow the 'path of least surprise' for your users.

Comment: Remove the default icon, replace it with your own, as part of the "message" component

Comment: How do I remove the default icon and put it as part of the "message" component?